# Android Studio OnCreate Never used warning

Tags: android

This is an rssfeed and everything compiles and I don't think i am missing anything but my app wont launch and there is a warning about my OnCreate never being used.  I am unsure if this is related to the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView src;
private Button btn;


protected void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    src = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Fetch);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fetch();
        }
    });
}
public void fetch() {
    Downloader d = new Downloader();
    d.execute("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    try {
        src.setText(d.get());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error to thread", e.toString());
    }
}

class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result + line;
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error to fetching", e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: *I don't think i am missing anything* what about glasses? use `@Override` above your `OnCreate` and you will see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct writing is `onCreate`, not `OnCreate`. Try to change that.

Answer (score 2):

OnCreate -->  onCreate  and use @Override